# One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints in SQL Script

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Need help on this.

I'm just wondering why this error occurred. Below is the script concerned.

```
    SELECT loc.ID
    ,loc.LocCode
    ,loc.LocName
    ,st.StateName
    ,reg.RegionName
    ,ctry.CountryName
    ,ISNULL(CONVERT(DATE, loc.UpdatedDate), CONVERT(DATE,loc.CreatedDate)) AS [ModifiedDate]
    ,stf.Name AS [ModifiedBy]
FROM Spkr_Country AS ctry WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Spkr_Location AS loc WITH (NOLOCK) ON ctry.ID = loc.CountryID
INNER JOIN Spkr_State AS st WITH (NOLOCK) ON loc.StateID = st.ID
INNER JOIN Spkr_Region AS reg WITH (NOLOCK) ON loc.RegionID = reg.ID
INNER JOIN Staff AS stf ON ISNULL(loc.UpdatedBy, loc.CreatedBy) = stf.StaffId
WHERE (loc.IsActive = 1)
    AND (
        (@LocCode = '')
        OR (
            @LocCode <> ''
            AND loc.LocCode LIKE @LocCode + '%'
            )
        )
    AND (
        (@RegionID < 1)
        OR (
            @RegionID > 0
            AND loc.RegionID = @RegionID
            )
        )
    AND (
        (@StateID < 1)
        OR (
            @StateID > 0
            AND loc.StateID = @StateID
            )
        )
    AND (
        (@CountryID < 1)
        OR (
            @CountryID > 0
            AND loc.CountryID = @CountryID
            )
        )
```

The error probably occurred here `INNER JOIN Staff AS stf ON ISNULL(loc.UpdatedBy, loc.CreatedBy) = stf.StaffId` The requirement that I wanted is that if the `loc.UpdatedBy` is null, it will use the `loc.CreatedBy` column. However, when I used this, it generated the error mentioned.

In the database, the `loc.CreatedBy` is not null while the `loc.UpdatedBy` is nullable.

I checked it by running the script but it's working fine.

How do I do with it? What's wrong with my code? Please help.

Comment: One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints <-- that's the error. The line concerned is the `INNER JOIN Staff AS stf ON ISNULL(loc.UpdatedBy, loc.CreatedBy) = stf.StaffId`. How do I revise this?

Comment: I want to know why this error occurred based on the script and how can I revise this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the inner join condition to this line of code.
`INNER JOIN Staff AS stf ON COALESCE(loc.UpdatedBy, loc.Createdby) = stf.StaffId`

However, I still don't know why it didn't work? What's the difference with using `COALESCE()` and `ISNULL()` in this scenario?